# ERROR IN PULLING DOCKER IMAGE IN WINDOWS 2016 SERVER (docker for windows)

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, dockerhub, docker-for-windows

. Not able to pull Microsoft images like microsoft/dotnet, microsoft/dotnet: 2.2-sdk, even though these are window based images, even experimental is TRUE in my settings then also throwing error.

ERROR - Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from microsoft/dotnet
no matching manifest for the unknown in the manifest list entries

. tried setting the experimental true,  tried reinstalling docker, tried restarting, switching to Linux containers then also same error .

. DOCKER VERSION

Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:28:48 2019
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     true

Answer (score 1):

Names in docker are case sensitive. It's "microsoft", with a lower case "m":

```
$ docker pull microsoft/dotnet
```

Comment: ...as are my eyes with respect to the title of the question... :)

Comment: sorry , i edited the question , that is microsoft/dotnet only that is throwing the error .